# How to get money value from string using PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, money-format

Is there a simple way to extract the money amount from a string using php?

For example, I have $1,419.99

I want to get in return 1419.99

Another example, I have $1,321

I want to get 1321 back.

I know I can manually remove $ and , but is there a way using something like preg_match to grab all the numbers and if any thing after the decimal, grab that as well and just return the number with no , or dollar sign? Seems like a simple solution but for some reason my mind is not wrapping around this.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout `NumberFormatter::parseCurrency`

Here's the link to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) for it

Comment: @John If PHP's `parseCurrency` can handle your use cases, this would be the way to go, as building a thorough regex would be substantially more work.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can used explode function. Like

```
$amount = '$1,419.99';
$money = explode('$', $amount);
echo $money[1];
```

Results: 1,419.99

Comment: The OP wants the result to be 1419.99 (no thousand separator).

Comment: than also use echo str_replace(',','' ,$money[1]);

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to use regular expression, you can try the below code

```
$amount = '$1,419.99';
$amount = preg_replace('/[^.a-zA-Z0-9]/s', '', $amount );
echo $amount;
```